# Windows Dump File Format

Tags: windows, dump

I've been working on creating better tooling to deal with dumps at my organization. With core dumps (linux) this is simple enough since they are ELF files with a known format.

However we have some Windows systems and the dumps produced by them do not seem to be ELF. I know there are windows tools so work with these files but I would like to expand our own to work with them.

Is the windows dump file format known? Or is it a MS secret?

Thanks!

Comment: Microsoft is not very keen on documenting file structures, once it is documented they can never change it again.  They strongly favor you [use the api instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/debug-help-library).   Well, not so useful on a *nix machine.  What you are looking for is however available, you'll find the core declarations in the DbgHelp.h SDK file.

Comment: How, precisely, are you trying to improve your tooling? Are you, by chance, trying to replicate what [Windows Error Reporting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wer/windows-error-reporting) does for you already?

Comment: @IInspectable no we are trying to create some tooling to automate some basic investigation that at the moment needs to be done with Windbg.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks I'll give that a read, it might be enough for my needs.