# How to compare and analyze two .dmp files?

Tags: java, windows, memory-dump, dmp

I have two virtual machines of WindosOS and I create two .dmp files for each of them. I want to open the first.dmp file and compare each line inside it with second.dmp file to see the difference. I want to write a java program to do this and two for loops sounds good.

The problem here is how to open the .dmp file. I know I can use WinDbg tool to open .dmp file, but how to open it in java program? Or is there any tool to convert .dmp into some formats I can open?

Comment: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53101728/windows-dump-file-format#comment93104986_53101728).

Comment: If you figure out .dmp format or how to use MS API to read what you need from it, you're going to want to research "longest common subsequence." There are a ton of different algorithms with different tradeoffs. It's a bit more complicated than a couple of for loops, but it's always good to learn new things.